# Will a pointer declaration to a structure allocate memory for its members?

Tags: c, pointers

[check the image of program on turbo c++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axwVe.png)

[output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwcpD.png)

```
#include< stdio.h>

struct node  {
    int data;
};

int main() {

    struct node *ptr;

    ptr->data=3;
    printf("%d",ptr->data);

    return 0;
}
```

Output: 3

My question is that even though I have not declared an instance of structure node.

e.g struct node n;

Also I have not assigned memory for ptr using malloc, it still allocates space for ptr->data. Why?
 Shouldn't it just assign memory for address ptr on stack.

And where this memory for data field is allocated, on stack or heap.---------

Comment: Please don't put a blank line between each and evry line in your sourc code

Comment: Please dont use a 20-year old compiler. You dont use a 20 year old phone or a car, why a compiler?

Comment: Oh, and concerning TurboC, I'd not use tools that are older than you, really. TurboC is totally outdated, and there are no valid reasons to use this tool today.

Comment: @SouravGhosh why not a 20 year old car ;-)

Comment: Ask yourself this (1) have I created an instance of the struct with *automatic storage type*?, or (2) have I allocated memory for it?

Comment: @Jabberwocky beause of change in emission regulations. :)

Comment: sure, i will take care of it next time

Comment: but kindly explain it now why it is working

Comment: @DeepChaudhary it is "working" because it is "undefined behaviour" (google that term). "Undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: [30 years old compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL1py.png). [30 years old car](https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7288/8739576189_ea2695b8ba_b.jpg). [30 years old phone](https://www.poptechmotive.com/uploads/3/4/9/2/3492988/published/motorola-micro-tac-1989.jpeg?1505861393). [30 years old computer](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bg1ZSxPOb0A/maxresdefault.jpg). You get the idea.

Comment: The age of physical objects is a bad analogy here, me thinks. All in all, ISO C itself is a 30 yr old language.

Answer (score 10):

In your code, `ptr->data=3;` invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as `ptr` does not point to any valid memory location.

You need to make sure that `ptr` points to a valid memory location before making any attempt to de-reference it.

It *appears* to work properly in your case, that is also one of the most dangerous side effects of undefined behavior.

That said, `ptr` is having automatic storage. The memory it would point to, will depend on the allocation used. C standard does not have a notion of stack or heap - that is dependent on the implementation.

Comment: when I am writing it in turbo c++ it is working fine

Comment: @DeepChaudhary As mentioned earlier, working fine is one of the side effects of UB.

Comment: You might want to include an answer for the final question; `where this memory for data field is allocated`.

Comment: @TimRandall That's a broad one .. especially because no allocation is shown. However, let me elaborate a bit.

Comment: @DeepChaudhary TC++ wrote all over the memory with little concern. It could write to string literals, data ports, memory belonging to other programs, the OS installation directory, anything. So when you invoked undefined behavior, it could appear to be working fine, or it could permanently kill your PC, or it could print a picture of a dead kitten on your fancy LPT port dot matrix printer.

Answer (score 3):

> Also I have not assigned memory for ptr using malloc, it still allocates space for ptr->data.

Nothing's been allocated.  Without an initializer, the value of `ptr` is *indeterminate*, and in this case *just happens* to point to memory that you can write to without immediately crashing your program.  You managed to not overwrite anything "important", but that's a matter of luck more than anything else.

You should get in the habit of initializing pointers as you declare them, either as `NULL` or as the result of the `&` operator or as the result of a `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc` call.

Comment: will this data field be overridden by some other program's memory requirement.

Comment: @DeepChaudhary: Possibly.  That's the problem with undefined behavior - it's *undefined*, and therefore unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the pointer  `struct node *ptr;` it will be placed on your stack.
The place where this variable is placed can be anywhere in your stack.

For example it is placed on address 0x100.

When the variable is placed on that location, the data that is there is not set to 0.
So on address `0x100` was the data `0x200` for example, you will have a `struct node *ptr` pointing to the address `0x200`.

Then at that point you are doing the following `ptr->data=3;` As the code thinks that there is a `struct node` placed at your address 0x200, it will fill the variable `data` in there. So on the address 0x200 will the value `3` be written.

When you are in luck (well actually it isn't really luck, as it could cause lots of problems later on) the writing of the value `3` at the address `0x200`will not cause any problems, because the memory at address `0x200` wasn't used.

But keep in mind that your code only THINKS that the `struct node` was placed at that location, but actually there isn't one, so any other variable could be on that location. And when there is a different variable on that address. when you write the value `3` to that address you are you are overwriting the value of that variable. And that could create some very strange behavior in your code.

Comment: Can you please explain the third paragraph again, I could not understand it.